# What is the most efficient events declaration way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am upgrading a web project containing 2 views with plenty of elements.

At this time, all elements have several events like `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `click`, ... **which are defined one by one during the web page rendering**.

My question is : is it **more efficient** to use the last jQuery method [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using an events map and a dynamic selector like this :

```
$("#main-container").on({
    mouseenter: function (event) {    
       //Do stuff
    },            
    mouseleave: function (event) {
       //Do stuff     
    },
    mousedown: function (event) {
       //Do stuff
    }
    },
    ".cartridge"
);
```

than the current events declarations:

```
$('[id^="cartridge"]').each(function(index) {       
    $(this).click(function(){
        //Do stuff
    }); 
    $(this).mouseenter(function(){
        //Do stuff
    }); 
    $(this).mouseleave(function(){
        //Do stuff
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the jquery API of .on() it is more efficient cause there's only one event attached to your #main-container and the events coming from the different .cartridge just need to "bubble up" to this container.

From jquery API :

> In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements
>   not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their
>   potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be
>   monitored. On a data table with 1,000 rows in its tbody, this example
>   attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:
>
> ```
> $("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
>   alert($(this).text());
> });
> ```
>
> A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one
>   element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level
>   (from the clicked tr to tbody):
>
> ```
> $("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
>   alert($(this).text());
> });
> ```

http://api.jquery.com/on/ see "Direct and delegated events"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did you already improve projects with .on()?

Comment: I've never "improved" any project that way. But you can notice a performance difference on pages with a lot of events, between declaring every event once on every object, and declaring it on the parent object.